# Method and method overloading

Tags: java

***Thank you! In the formatted output statements, are the .2 and .4 in the %f's wrong as well? I cant seem to see a reason for them being their. Also, I changed the variables to match the methods. but where does the string color come into this? Should they be private or public ***

This is week 6 of my Java class and up until this moment I have had absolutely no problems understanding and completing the assignments in this class. For some reason I don't understand this!

All I am supposed to be doing is answering what is wrong with this code by providing the line numbers that their is an issue with along with a fix.

I am not asking for the answer. Rather, an explanation!
I can tell you what is wrong with the print lines, I just don't know or understand what is wrong or missing in the methods.

***Assignment details: What is wrong with this code? Provide the line numbers and fix(es) if any. Please Note: Consider the variable declaration lines 6 & 7 to be correct as they are presented.***

```
    //Instantiate a new Scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declarations
    double rad1;        //radius 1 - used for circle and ellipse
    double rad2;        //radius 2 - used for the ellipse w/rad1

    System.out.print("Enter radius one: ");
    rad1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter radius two: ");
    rad2 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("The area of a circle with a radius of %.2f "
            + "equals %.4f\n", rad1, circularArea(rad1));
    System.out.printf("The area of an ellipse with a radius of %.2f "
            + "and %.2f equals %.4f\n", r1, r2, circularArea(rad1, rad2));

} //End Main Method

/*Method: circularArea() 
 *@ params: r1
 */
private static double circularArea(int r1) {
    return Math.PI * Math.pow(r1, 2);
}//End circularArea method

/*Method: circularArea() - overloaded
 *@ params: r1, r2
 */
private static double circularArea(double r1, double r2, String color) {
    return Math.PI * r1 * r2;
}//End overloaded circularArea method
```

Comment: @JohnJoe please read carefully,  "I am not asking for the answer... Rather, an explanation!"

Comment: Follow the variable declarations, what types are they? Are they used correctly? Are they compatible with the methods?

Comment: **Count** the method arguments as well...and how many are you using?

Comment: The parameters for the second circularArea method did not matched

Comment: Hint: Check the return type of the functions: private static double circularArea(int r1) and private static double circularArea(double r1, double r2, String color). When you ask the input in rad1 and rad2... do you see any diferences?

Comment: Thank you! In the formatted output statements, are the .2 and .4 in the %f's wrong as well? I cant seem to see a reason for them being their. Also,

Comment: ... I changed the variables to match the methods. but where does the string color come into this? Should they be private or public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error appears to be on this line: `rad1 = sc.nextInt();` The method `nextInt()` in the `Scanner` class returns an Integer, but, if you look up a few lines, your `rad1` variable is defined as a `double`. This isn't *really* an error, and I don't *think* it would crash, but it's inconsistent.

The more blatant error would occur on this line:

```
System.out.printf("The area of an ellipse with a radius of %.2f and %.2f equals %.4f\n", r1, r2, circularArea(rad1, rad2));
```

You call the `circularArea` method with two arguments, and the method does require these two arguments, but it also requires a `String` called `color`. Either the `color` argument needs to be removed from the method declaration or added to the method invocation.

Also, I applaud you on your method for learning. I didn't care about *why* I was wrong, I just tried to fix it. This lead to many problems in the future, so keep doing it the way you're doing it, and figuring out the source of the problem. It makes your life a *lot* easier.